# How can I mount ActiveDirectory in powershell with X500 format?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

when I try to mount Active Directory in powershell, it raises the below error:
"""The object name has bad syntax new-psprovider""".

It can only bypassed if you provide the option -format canon.

But I want to mount it by X500 format.

```
PS mtn:\> mount ad -PSProvider ActiveDirectory -Root $root -Server $server -Credential $cred
```

OR

```
PS mtn:\> mount ad -PSProvider ActiveDirectory -Root $root -Server $server -Credential $cred -FormatType X500
```

Error:

```
mount : The object name has bad syntax
At line:1 char:1
+ mount ad -PSProvider ActiveDirectory -Root $root -Server $server -Crede ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ad:PSDriveInfo) [New-PSDrive], ADException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId :     ADProvider:NewDrive:InvalidRoot:ADError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSDriveCommand
```

Comment: I suspect problem in `$root` variable. Could you edit post and add part of code were you define it?

Comment: I can easily mount the PSDrive if the option -formatType Canonical is provided. anyway, the values are these: $root=iat.pt, $server=ad.iat.pt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the `$root` syntax is wrong, after all. It has to be in the DistinguishedName (DN) format, with the example being my company’s domain, `intranet.lan`:

```
DC=intranet,DC=lan
```

Comment: you are right, the root syntax should follow the FormatType convention.